# Minor nitpick in color and icon of job alert

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

This link really is an eyesore on jobs.
Can we change its color to the standard blue to go with the rest of the page.
The icon can go as well, it is hard to tell what the icon even is.

[image]

Comment: The icon looks like a bell to me even on this low-resolution screenshot; I'm not sure I'd advocate removing it. The color should definitely be changed, though.

Comment: @Undo - I'm not saying I don't see it, I'm just saying its unnecessary.  It looks pretty crappy on the site.