# How do I remove job alerts with the new interface

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I clicked subscribe to weekly top job matches but want to remove this:

[image]

Comment: PS: Thanks for addressing this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320864/minor-nitpick-in-color-and-icon-of-job-alert If one of the developers can add as an answer I can close out this issue.  You have to admit this looks much better than that darn green bell.

Answer (score 4):

You can unsubscribe on the [Manage Job Alerts view](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts). You can access this view from the footer of the "Top Job Matches" email. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Why is this view only on the email, this is not intuitive nor is it easily discover-able.